# AngularJS - service changes controller data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I discovered that when I call a service method within my controller and pass to it an object as a parameter, any changes that are done to that object (inside service method) are also made to the original object from my controller.

I always thought that controller data should stay unchanged until I changed it inside promise win/error event and only if I need to.

JS sample:

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, simpleService){
  $scope.data = { d: 1, c: 10};

  $scope.clickMe = function(){
    simpleService.clickMe($scope.data).then(function(res){
      alert($scope.data.d);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      alert($scope.data.d);
    });

  }

});

app.factory('simpleService', function($q){
  var simpleServiceMethods = {};

  simpleServiceMethods.clickMe = function(data){
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    //data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); - solution: clone data without references

    data.d = 1111;

    deffered.reject();

    return deffered.promise;
  }

  return simpleServiceMethods;
});
```

Plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nHz2T7D2mJ0zXWjZZKP3?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, do you know about AngularJS databinding?

Comment: The issue is that the service changes my controller data. Is it normal?

Comment: It is if you pass your $scope variable to the service and then change it. This is how AngularJS databinding works

Comment: Ok, then try to change ``$scope.data = ...`` with ``var data = ...`` and also replace all ``$scope.data`` - the same will happen.

Comment: Keep the $scope stuff, but pass ```angular.copy($scope.data)``` to the function. Also please do ```alert(res.d)```

Comment: That or the solution I have written in the service, both works. I just wanted to know why and if it is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the nature of angular's databinding. If you want to pass the details of a `$scope` variable you could make use of angular's cloning capability with `copy` or update your services to work slightly differently by creating a copy on the service side. Normal CRUD style applications you'd normally be passing the `id` of an entity, receiving a new entity or posting changes which may in most cases already be present client side.

Comment: even if I don't pass a ``$scope`` variable I have the same behaviour. does that apply to normal objects as well?

Comment: If the service is making changes to whatever is passed to it then yes, you would expect those changes. If you don't want changes made to the original thing being passed to the service you could create a copy within the service, make alterations to that and then return that instead of what was originally passed.

Comment: got it. this is the 1st time I encountered this situation in 9 months of working with Angular and that's why I got confused. As you said, until now I was passing only the ``id`` of an entity, but this time I had to pass the whole thing.

Comment: No problem. We have all been there :D